# Multi port cantainers with nginx-proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, docker-compose

I'm currently running a container with my web application and it communicates through two ports, for the frontend and backend.
I'm using jwilder/nginx-proxy to serve the applictions.
When I run the docker compose file (which starts the app and the proxy) it gives me a 502 Bad gateway
when I run with only one port it serves that part of the app.
Im passing the port with the "VIRTUAL_PORT=80" is there a way to pass more than one port or if I make a separate container for the Frontend how would I get the proxy to speak to both containers with one request?
In short does jwilder/nginx-proxy support multiport containers, and if not what's the workaround?
Thank in advance!

Docker-compose.yml

```
reverseproxy:  
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy

  ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock

myapp:
  depends_on:
    - reverseproxy
  build: ./app-files
  environment:
     - "VIRTUAL_HOST=my-domain.com"
     - "VIRTUAL_PORT=80,8080"
  expose:
     - 80
     - 8080
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy, i don't think this is supported. Open a issue with them and see what the author says

Comment: I opened an issue with them. Do you @TarunLalwani know of a way to split an app into two?(the code is seperable)

Comment: Usually people use `subdomain` in that case, if you want ouse `nginx-proxy` then i think subdomain approach would work